# Why 3 root 2 is equal to 3 divided by root 2 in this quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

As part of my research into quadratics, I am trying to show algebraically the following equation :

$${x^2-3\sqrt2 x + 4}  = 0$$

alternatively shown as $x^2 - 3 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}}x + 4 = 0$

Now, my question is... how is it possible for the above equation to end up as $\left(x-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - \dfrac{1}{2} =0$

If it helps, inputting the above into wolframalpha may reduce the confusion.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align} \left(x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2} &= \left(x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(x-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \\
\\
&= x^2 - \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x - \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}x + \frac{9}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\
\\
&= x^2 - \frac{2\cdot 3}{\sqrt{2}}x + \frac{8}{2} \\
\\
&= x^2 - 3\sqrt{2}x + 4
\end{align}
$$